# how to populate JSON response(POST) in spinner using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Dear friends here what am looking for need to populate spinner which is a JSON response from rest service using retrofit. After a long research, I can't find any samples on this can anyone share some sample based on this would be very useful for me thanks in advance!

This is the JSON response kindly help me parse and populate in the spinner.

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "ServiceType:#TVS_Complaint_BL.Entities",
            "Message": "OK",
            "Success": true,
            "ServiceCode": "P1",
            "ServiceName": "Paid Service",
            "nServiceID": 1
        },
        {
            "__type": "ServiceType:#TVS_Complaint_BL.Entities",
            "Message": "OK",
            "Success": true,
            "ServiceCode": "F1",
            "ServiceName": "Free Service",
            "nServiceID": 2
        },
        {
            "__type": "ServiceType:#TVS_Complaint_BL.Entities",
            "Message": "OK",
            "Success": true,
            "ServiceCode": "PS1",
            "ServiceName": "Post Warranty",
            "nServiceID": 3
        },
        {
            "__type": "ServiceType:#TVS_Complaint_BL.Entities",
            "Message": "OK",
            "Success": true,
            "ServiceCode": "FOC",
            "ServiceName": "FOC",
            "nServiceID": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Vehicle Response:

```
public class VehicleResponse {


    private List<DBean> d;

    public List<DBean> getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(List<DBean> d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public static class DBean {
        /**
         * __type : ServiceType:#TVS_Complaint_BL.Entities
         * Message : OK
         * Success : true
         * ServiceCode : P1
         * ServiceName : Paid Service
         * nServiceID : 1
         */

        private String __type;
        private String Message;
        private boolean Success;
        private String ServiceCode;
        private String ServiceName;
        private int nServiceID;

        public String get__type() {
            return __type;
        }

        public void set__type(String __type) {
            this.__type = __type;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return Message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String Message) {
            this.Message = Message;
        }

        public boolean isSuccess() {
            return Success;
        }

        public void setSuccess(boolean Success) {
            this.Success = Success;
        }

        public String getServiceCode() {
            return ServiceCode;
        }

        public void setServiceCode(String ServiceCode) {
            this.ServiceCode = ServiceCode;
        }

        public String getServiceName() {
            return ServiceName;
        }

        public void setServiceName(String ServiceName) {
            this.ServiceName = ServiceName;
        }

        public int getNServiceID() {
            return nServiceID;
        }

        public void setNServiceID(int nServiceID) {
            this.nServiceID = nServiceID;
        }
    }
}
```

Vechile Request:

```
public class VehicleRequest {


    /**
     * argRequest : {"Token":"356657bba5a94daeb02a2a5bd93c6b71"}
     */

    private ArgRequestBean argRequest;

    public ArgRequestBean getArgRequest() {
        return argRequest;
    }

    public void setArgRequest(ArgRequestBean argRequest) {
        this.argRequest = argRequest;
    }

    public static class ArgRequestBean {
        /**
         * Token : 356657bba5a94daeb02a2a5bd93c6b71
         */

        private String Token;

        public String getToken() {
            return Token;
        }

        public void setToken(String Token) {
            this.Token = Token;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are fetching JSON using retrofit ? Post that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Gson when you are consuming API with Retrofit. Following dependencies should work according to the documentation:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'  

}
```

After retrieving the response data, you can reach each instance of DBean by using Gson.
Supposing that your response data is fetch as `Response<JsonObject> response`:

```
gson = new Gson();    
List<DBean> dBeanList = new ArrayList<>();

JsonObject jsonObject = gson.toJsonTree(response.body()).getAsJsonObject();
dBeanList = jsonObject.getD().getAsJsonArray();
```

Then you can populate the spinner with the list of `DBean`'s:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<DBean> adapterDBeans = new ArrayAdapter<> 
(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dBeanList);

adapterDBeans.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapterDBeans);
```

References: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit